# QGIS 3: saga algorithm in console

Tags: qgis-processing, saga, qgis-3, parameters

I'm trying to use the saga algorithm 'quadtree structure to polygon' (with points to get polygons), in the python console. 
But I think I'm not able to set the parameters correctly.

When I call the algorithm help, I get :

```
----------------
Input parameters
----------------

SHAPES:  <QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource>
    Shapes

ATTRIBUTE:  <QgsProcessingParameterField>
    Attribute

POLYGONS:  <QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination>
    Polygons

LINES:  <QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination>
    Lines

POINTS:  <QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination>
    Duplicated Points

----------------
Outputs
----------------

POLYGONS:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
    Polygons

LINES:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
    Lines

POINTS:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
    Duplicated Points
```

Moreover, I get the error :

```
NameError: name 'QgsProcessingFeedback' is not defined
```

So I tried this...

```
from qgis.core import (QgsMessageLog,
                   QgsApplication,
                   QgsMapLayer,
                   QgsProcessingProvider,
                   QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                   QgsProcessingException,
                   QgsProcessingParameterDefinition,
                   QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer,
                   QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer,
                   QgsProcessingOutputMapLayer,
                   QgsProcessingOutputMultipleLayers,
                   QgsProcessingFeedback)
```

... but still the same error.

How can I use this algorithm?

Comment: What's the error? Does it work when you run it from the toolbox?